# Excluding httpclient/httpcore in jboss-deployment-structure

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I recently updated apache httpclient to 4.5.1 and httpcore to 4.4.4, but for some reason my Jboss server has older versions of both (4.3.6).  I'm pulling in the new versions via ivy, but they seem to be getting overwritten by the versions on the server.  I've tried making my own jboss-deployment-structure.xml file, but it doesn't seem to be working and the documentation is scarce on exactly how this piece functions.  At what level of specificity do I need to be blocking modules to prevent jboss loading dependencies that override ivy?

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" />
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
        <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Progress update: looks like the application relies on jaxrs and xalan, which in turn pull in the dependencies.  ugh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the hibernate 3 jboss-eap-quickstarts:

```
<exclusions>
    <!-- Exclude container version of hibernate. By default its version 4, we want 
        bundled version 3 loaded -->
    <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
</exclusions>
```

In your build for your application in the dependencies that pull in jaxrs and xalan set the scope of httpclient and httpcore to provided.